# Using GROUP BY to sum the values of columns in rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has the following fields;

```
id (int)
line_id (int)
cell_no (int)
timestamp (datetime)
total (int)
passed (int)
data_type (varchar)
created_at (datetime)
updated_at (datetime)
```

With the table, there are multiple rows which contain a `cell_no` of the same value. I want to query the table, merge all rows with the same `cell_no` value, sum the total of passed and total for each distinct `cell_no`, and then return the results sorted by passed / total in ascending order.

I can get this working fine in MySQL, but I can't get it working in MSSQL as it complains that some fields are not in the group by definition, but when I put them in the group by, the rows where the `cell_no` is the same are not merged.

Here's how I have the query in MySQL;

```
SELECT id, cell_no, data_type, sum(total) AS total, sum(passed) AS passed
FROM line_data AS ld
WHERE line_id = 1
      AND timestamp >= '2018-07-29 00:00:00'
      AND timestamp <= '2018-07-29 23:00:00'
GROUP BY cell_no
ORDER BY ((passed / total) * 100) ASC
```

How would I present this to MSSQL?

Comment: You need to tell us _which_ values from each group you want to report for the `id` and `data_type` columns.  MySQL's lax syntax is letting you get away with this query, but as you're seeing now, it won't run really anywhere else.

Comment: Use a proper `GROUP BY`.  Your query won't even run on any dbms except for maybe MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your query is invalid SQL. Per `cell_no` there exist multiple `id` and `data_type` and you don't tell the DBMS which to pick.

MySQL silently converts your select clause to

```
SELECT
  ANY_VALUE(id),
  cell_no,
  ANY_VALUE(data_type),
  SUM(total) AS total,
  SUM(passed) AS passed
```

The function `ANY_VALUE(id)` means you don't care which of the cell_no's IDs to pick for the results.

`ANY_VALUE` is not available in SQL Server, but as you obviously don't care which value, you can replace it by `MIN` or `MAX`:

```
SELECT
  MIN(id),
  cell_no,
  MIN(data_type),
  SUM(total) AS total,
  SUM(passed) AS passed
```

**UPDATE:** Another issue may be your `ORDER BY` clause. 7 / 2 is 3.5 in MySQL (as should be expected), but only 3 in SQL Server, because SQL Server sees a division of two integers and wants the result to be an integer, too. You can convert one or both integers to decimal to get a decimal result:

```
ORDER BY (CAST(passed AS DECIMAL) / total) * 100 ASC
```

Comment: Nice explanation. I do not know how MySql works, but i know how MsSql works. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes:

- You can only select fields aggregated or specified on group by.
- You have to aggregate/sum the totals on order by.

You have three options to fix them.

1. Remove `id` column from select

   ```
   SELECT cell_no, SUM(total) AS total, SUM(passed) AS passed
   FROM line_data AS ld
   WHERE line_id = 1
     AND timestamp >= '2018-07-29 00:00:00'
     AND timestamp <= '2018-07-29 23:00:00'
   GROUP BY cell_no
   ORDER BY ((SUM(passed)/ SUM(total)) * 100) ASC
   ```
2. Add `id` column to your `group by`:

   ```
   SELECT 
       id, cell_no, data_type, 
       SUM(total) AS total, SUM(passed) AS passed
   FROM line_data AS ld
   WHERE line_id = 1
     AND timestamp >= '2018-07-29 00:00:00'
     AND timestamp <= '2018-07-29 23:00:00'
   GROUP BY id, cell_no, data_type
   ORDER BY ((SUM(passed) / SUM(total)) * 100) ASC
   ```
3. Aggregate `id` column (with max, min or ....)

   ```
   SELECT 
       MAX(id), cell_no, data_type, 
       SUM(total) AS total, SUM(passed) AS passed
   FROM line_data AS ld
   WHERE line_id = 1
     AND timestamp >= '2018-07-29 00:00:00'
     AND timestamp <= '2018-07-29 23:00:00'
   GROUP BY cell_no, data_type
   ORDER BY ((SUM(passed)/ SUM(total)) * 100) ASC
   ```

Comment: Good point about the aliases. Yes, that's ambiguous, the aggregated values have the same names as the non-aggregated ones. I think the alias names should have precedence over the original names, but I neither don't know how the SQL standard defines that nor how MySQL or SQL Server implement it. It's just a bad idea to name the aggregate results like the columns.

Comment: Yes, you will need to aggregate it again on the order by.

Answer (score 0):

All fields in the Select statement that aren't being aggregated need to be in the Group by.

`SELECT id, cell_no, data_type, sum(total) AS total, sum(passed) AS passed, (sum(passed)/sum(total)*100) as percent_passed
FROM line_data AS ld
WHERE line_id = 1
      AND timestamp >= '2018-07-29 00:00:00'
      AND timestamp <= '2018-07-29 23:00:00'
GROUP BY id, cell_no, data_type
ORDER BY 6 ASC`

Edited to include the percent passed in the select statement, and then order by 6 to order by column 6.

Comment: This would work, but it changes the meaning of the query.

Comment: Why are you adding percent_passed column? Just to order by a index? See my answer.

Comment: Partially to be able to order by an index, but also because I expect the calculation will occur, as it is likely important to the data set.